# STATIC files are not showed in Django templates

Tags: python, django, templates, static, settings

I'm trying to show images/js/css in my Django templates with {{ STATIC_URL }} label. In theory, this works because in browser, when i see the printed code the path to requested file is something like "/static/images/blabla.jpg". But the file is not showed, so i guess the problem is in Django project.

My settings looks like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/absolute/path/to/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    '/absolute/path/to/static'
)
```

In my urls.py:

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

But i don't know why all files in static directory are not displayed in templates.

Any tip or advice?

Thanks mates.

Comment: What happens when you open  /static/images/blabla.jpg in your browser ? Please post full details.

Comment: Browser returns HTTP 404 error. For example, http://localhost:8000/static/images/hi.jpg and it isn't displayed. Only 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it *looks* like there is a mistake in your settings. You should understand the [django.contrib.staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic) command:

> Collects the static files into STATIC_ROOT.
>   [...]
>   Files are searched by using the enabled finders. The default is to look in all locations defined in STATICFILES_DIRS and in the 'static' directory of apps specified by the INSTALLED_APPS setting.

So, it seems like a mistake that [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std%3asetting-STATICFILES_DIRS) contains [STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATIC_ROOT), since the contents of [STATICFILES_DIR](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std%3asetting-STATICFILES_DIRS) is ment to be copied into [STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATIC_ROOT) by [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic).

The url is not necessary. You should either:

- use runserver with DEBUG=True, in that case django will [serve static files by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#basic-usage), in doubt use [staticfiles_urlpatterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#staticfiles-development) or
- use a real httpd to serve [STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATIC_ROOT) on STATIC_URL, in that case you should generate [STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-STATIC_ROOT) from [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std%3asetting-STATICFILES_DIRS) (and actually each app's 'static' subdir, which is the point) with the command [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic)

When in doubt, the [findstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-findstatic) command may also prove useful.

django.contrib.staticfiles might look a little confusing at first, but when you understand it fully you love it <3

Comment: Omg, now i understand how it works (or almost). I have modified my settings.py and urls.py (deleted static_urlpatterns) and now all already work as expected.

Thanks a lot man. I would vote you, but i cannot yet. Sorry =(